# Return specific values from a nested dictionary with a generator function

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, generator, nested-lists, yield

I have a list of dict containing nested dict which looks like below. I would like to use generators and yield to go over `reviews` list of dict and return all `rating` given a specific `user` value. For example `"user" : "A11"` has two `rating` records. I would like to have these returned as dict.

```
data = [{ "product_id" : "123",
    "size" : "L",
    "color" : "blue",
    "reviews" : [
        { "user" : "A11", "rating" : "score1" },
        { "user" : "Z99", "rating" : "score" }] },

    { "product_id" : "987",
    "size" : "M",
    "color" : "red",
    "reviews" : [
        { "user" : "A11", "rating" : "score2" },
        { "user" : "X55", "rating" : "score" }] }
    ]
```

I have the following generator but it is basically returning all `rating` values regardless of the `user`. How can I make the function to filter the values to a specific `user` ?

```
def user_rating(nest, kv):
    if isinstance(nest, list):
        for i in nest:
            for x in user_rating(i, kv):
                yield x
    elif isinstance(nest, dict):
        if kv in nest:
            yield nest[kv]
        for j in nest.values():
            for x in user_rating(j, kv):
                yield x

print(list(user_rating(data, 'rating')))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A little modify should be enough:

```
def user_rating(nest, kv):
    if isinstance(nest, list):
        for i in nest:
            yield from user_rating(i, kv)
    elif isinstance(nest, dict):
        if nest.get('user') == kv: # <----- here
            yield nest # <---- and here
        for j in nest.values():
            yield from user_rating(j, kv)
                
print(list(user_rating(data, 'A11')))
#[{'user': 'A11', 'rating': 'score1'}, {'user': 'A11', 'rating': 'score2'}]
```

Btw you can use `yield from` to ... well, yield from another generator instead of using a `for` loop

Comment: Thanks man, you are a godsend!